# Garbage collector example doesn't hold

Tags: java, garbage-collection

i was reading the thinking in java chapter about the garbage collector, and i found out an example which is running once upon a while. But i can't figure out why.

```
public class Book {

boolean checkedOut = false;

Book(boolean checkOut) {
    checkedOut = checkOut;
}

void checkIn() {
    checkedOut = false;
}

@Override
protected void finalize() {
    if (checkedOut) {
        System.out.println("Error: checked out");
    }
    // Normally, you’ll also do this:
    //super.finalize(); // Call the base-class version
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Book novel = new Book(true);
// Proper cleanup:
    novel.checkIn();
// Drop the reference, forget to clean up:
    new Book(true);
// Force garbage collection & finalization:
    System.gc();
    }
}
```

The call to `System.gc()` should force finalization of objects even if the memory is not running out.

Thus why the programs output **Error: checked out** only after 4-5 execution in a row? i can't get the point, can you try to clarify it out please?
I expect that everytime the GC is called the finalize method is executed as well, thus everytime the check out error should be promped.

Thanks

Comment: Question is unclear. Can you please elaborate what behavior are you expecting?

Comment: Didn't try to grok your example, but running `finalize` is not guaranteed.

Comment: See the workaround that I have provided in my code. In my environment it executed 4 times in a row.

Comment: And this, children, is why you should always use proper abstractions (namely, RAII and deterministic object destruction provided by it), instead of wrong ones (namely, GC giving no guarantees on object lifetimes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read the documentation?

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29

> Calling the gc method **suggests** that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a **best effort** to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

(emphasis mine)

It does not say "after this call, you are guaranteed that all unrooted objects will have been reclaimed and their finalizers executed". You give the GC a *suggestion* that taking a look at whether there's any data to reclaim, would be a good idea. No more than that.

(Also, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#runFinalization%28%29 might be a better match for what you actually *want* to happen, since the code you have shown us checks whether the object's finalizer has executed, not whether the object has been garbage collected)

Comment: so is only a suggestion? what i really want to force it?

Comment: Why would you want to force it?

Comment: i'm asking for knowledge. i found out the example in the book and wondered why wasn't working. The author exposed it as it was obliged to always execute the finalization.

Comment: Well, the answer is, "you don't want to force it". The GC runs when it needs to run. Usually, calling the function manually does nothing other than slow your program down a bit (the GC is most efficient when it can collect a big batch of memory.)

Comment: Man i understood this. I was trying to point out how to do it, i know is worse doing it. I was just looking for and academic purpose how to do it. 
Seems that using a combination of gc and runFinalization calls the finalization methods. i think we can close here discussion ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible that an *object never gets garbage collected* (and thus `finalize` is never called).

This can happen when the object *never becomes eligible for gc* (because it's reachable through the ***entire lifetime of the JVM***) or when no garbage collection actually runs between the time the object become eligible and the time the JVM stops running (**this often occurs with simple test programs**).

There is no guarantee that `finalize()` will ever be called.

***NOTE:*** If you are doing it for understanding purposes then its fine but you should avoid calling `System.gc()` explicitly.

DISCLAIMER: I am not saying this is a proper way of doing it. I just tried it thinking if there was some delay before the call to delay maybe the object created would be detected by gc and would get collected every time.

WORKAROUND (Not guaranteed to work)

```
Thread.sleep(10000); //try sleeping for a while before giving a call to gc
// Force garbage collection & finalization:
    System.gc();
```

Printed the desired output 4 times in a row on my environment.

Comment: On which planet is "block the thread for 10 seconds" a useful workaround?

Comment: @jalf I just posted it as there would be some delay before gc would get a chance to run. And also I tried it on my environment. If it seems vague I will remove it? What do you suggest?